# Background Image Don't Show up in Outlook 2013

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, vml

I have problem with background image in Outlook 2007/2010/2013.

Code:

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" border="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td background="http://i.imgur.com/YJOX1PC.png" bgcolor="" width="500" height="150" valign="top">
            <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false"                                                        style="width:100%;height:150px">
                <v:fill type="tile" src="http://i.imgur.com/YJOX1PC.png" color="#7bceeb" />
                <v:textbox style="mso-fit-shape-to-text:true" inset="0,0,0,0">
            <![endif]-->
            <table cellpadding="0" align="center" cellspacing="0" border="0" height="100%" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="" valign="top" align="center">
                        <img width="320" style="width: 100%; max-width: 320px;height: auto;"                                                    src="https://7maravilhas.pt/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/turismo-2.png">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                </v:textbox>
                </v:rect>
            <![endif]-->
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I already tried everithyng ( heights , widths , any kind of code ) non works.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add background-image in the td’s style, like this:

```
 <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" align="center">
      <tr>   

         <td background="http://i.imgur.com/YJOX1PC.png" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="150" width="500" style="background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/YJOX1PC.png)" bgcolor="" width="600" height="325" valign="top">

          <!--[if gte mso 9]>
            <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:600px;height:325px;">
            <v:fill type="tile" src="http://i.imgur.com/YJOX1PC.png" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="150" width="500" style="background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/YJOX1PC.png)" color="#7bceeb" />
            <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
          <![endif]-->
          <table width="100%" height="100%" align="center"  border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

          </table>
          <!--[if gte mso 9]>
        </v:textbox>
      </v:rect>
      <![endif]-->
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

For more information, please reference these links:

[Background Image Not Loading in Outlook 2013](https://litmus.com/community/discussions/6766-background-image-not-loading-in-outlook-2013)

[Background Image on Windows/Outlook Not Displaying](https://litmus.com/community/discussions/6068-background-image-on-windows-outlook-not-displaying)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have this declared in your

```
<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
 xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
```

I use this for my VML.  Its similar to yours but I use `<!--[if gte mso]>` instead of `<!--[if gte mso 9]>`

Try this:

```
<!--[if gte mso]><v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width: 640px"> <v:fill type="frame"
      src="http://i.imgur.com/YJOX1PC.png"
      color="#7bceeb"
      /> <v:textbox style="mso-fit-shape-to-text:true" inset="0,0,0,0"> <![endif]-->
       <div>

</div>
      <!--[if gte mso]><p style="margin:0;mso-hide:all"><o:p xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">&nbsp;</o:p></p> </v:textbox> </v:rect> <![endif]-->
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Important things are:

- You use a .png so you have to declare that it is allowed in Outlook with "AllowPNG"
- In your DOCTYPE and html you need some extra settings for the VML
- Some extra css is handy to reset vml elements (the stuff in the css like v:* ...)

Use this template as a starting point:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word">
<head>
  <!--[if (!mso)&(!ie)]>These<!-- --><!--<![endif]-->
  <!--[if (!mso)&(!ie)]>are<!-- --><!--<![endif]-->
  <!--[if (!mso)&(!ie)]>for<!-- --><!--<![endif]-->
  <!--[if (!mso)&(!ie)]>outlook<!-- --><!--<![endif]-->
  <!--[if (!mso)&(!ie)]>live<!-- --><!--<![endif]-->
  <!--[if (!mso)&(!ie)]>that<!-- --><!--<![endif]-->
  <!--[if (!mso)&(!ie)]>removes<!-- --><!--<![endif]-->
  <!--[if (!mso)&(!ie)]>the first<!-- --><!--<![endif]-->
  <!--[if (!mso)&(!ie)]>10 conditional<!-- --><!--<![endif]-->
  <!--[if (!mso)&(!ie)]>wellformed comments<!-- --><!--<![endif]-->
    <!--[if gte mso 9]>
    <xml>
      <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
        <o:AllowPNG/>
        <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
      </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
    </xml>
    <![endif]-->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="The title" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>The title</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      v\:* {
        behavior: url(#default#VML);
        display: inline-block
      }
      o\:* {
        behavior: url(#default#VML);
        display: inline-block
      }
      w\:* {
        behavior: url(#default#VML);
        display: inline-block
      }
      .ExternalClass{
        width:100%;
      }
      .ExternalClass,
      .ExternalClass p,
      .ExternalClass span,
      .ExternalClass font,
      .ExternalClass td,
      .ExternalClass div {
        line-height: 100%;
      }
      body {
        width: 100% !important;
        min-width: 100%;
        -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
        -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        Margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      table{
        border-spacing: 0;
        border-collapse:collapse;
        mso-table-lspace:0pt;
        mso-table-rspace:0pt;
      }  
      img {
        outline: none;
        text-decoration: none;
        -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
        width: auto;
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
      }
      .ReadMsgBody{
        width:100%;
      }
      td {
        -webkit-hyphens: auto;
        -moz-hyphens: auto;
        hyphens: auto;
        border-collapse: collapse !important;
      }
      p
      {
        margin: 0 0 20px 0;
        Margin: 0 0 20px 0;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        Margin-bottom: 20px;
      }
      @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
        .content-wrapper{
          width: 100% !important;
          max-width: 100% !important;
        }
        .gmail-fix {
          width: 0 !important;
          display: none !important;
        }
      }
      /* NO NORMAL CSS BETWEEN OR AFTER MEDIA QUERIES! they all get stripped in gmail */
    </style>
    </head>
    <body width="100%" style="margin:0; Margin: 0; padding:0;">
     <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" width="100%" style="margin:0; Margin: 0; padding:0;">
      <!-- GMAIL fix, keep min 600px when no media queries supported and keep this on top of email -->
      <tr class="gmail-fix">
        <td>
          <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
              <td height="0" width="600" style="font-size: 0; line-height: 0; width: 600px; min-width: 600px; height: 0;">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td align="center" width="100%" valign="top">
        <!--[if (mso)|(ie)]>
        <table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="600">
          <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="top" width="600">
              <![endif]-->
              <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" class="content-wrapper" style="max-width:600px;">
                <tr>
                  <td align="center">
                    <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="max-width:100%;">
                      <tr>
                        <td valign="top" background="http://i.imgur.com/YJOX1PC.png" style="background-repeat: repeat;">
                          <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                            <div>
                            <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width: 600px; height:225px;">
                              <v:fill type="tile" src="http://i.imgur.com/YJOX1PC.png" />
                              <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
                                <![endif]-->
                                  <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                    <tr>
                                      <td align="center" height="150">
                                        Your content or a non-breaking-space if you leave td's empty
                                      </td>
                                    </tr>
                                  </table>
                                <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                              </v:textbox>
                            </v:rect>
                            </div>
                          <![endif]-->
                        </td>
                      </tr> 
                      </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
                <!--[if (mso)|(ie)]>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <![endif]-->
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

With the introduction of Outlook 2007 and a number of web-based email clients, support for background images has basically been removed. If you know that your contacts are only using email clients that still render background images, then go for it; but as a general rule, avoid using background images (using CSS to call background images does not work either.)

Comment: Thanks , so how can i made it

Comment: This [link](https://medium.com/@jasemiller/a-fix-for-outlook-image-issues-in-html-email-campaigns-b8dd1c8f7d16) might help.